# Why npm gets stuck when installing browser-sync?

Tags: npm

When attempting to install Browser-syn [sudo npm install -g browser-sync] on Ubuntu, it gets stuck, the last readout is [loadDep:is-fullwidth-code].
I have been trying various solutions pertaining issues with npm, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work.
I removed nodejs v4.2.6 (that came with Ubuntu 16.04), an old package manager npm was also removed.
I installed nodejs v6.11.5 (that came with npm v3.10.10) following instructions on https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/.
I used npm to install browser-sync  [$ sudo npm install -g browser-sync] 
as indicated on https://www.browsersync.io/. 
It worked this time.